# asp: linqdatasource groupBy instead of Distinct

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an `<asp:LinqDataSource>` on my .Net 2.5 web form and am trying to use the groupby to get all distinct values as a 'hacky way' of getting around the problem that you cannot do a select distinct.

When grouping by Surname and Forename, I get an error that says:

#### No property or field 'staffID' exists in type 'IGrouping`2'

my code is:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsNewApps" runat="server" 
 ContextTypeName="siteDBDataContext" OrderBy="Surname" GroupBy="new(Surname, Forename)"
 Select="new (staffID, Forename, Surname, City, Country, LastUpdatedDate, tblStaffStatus, Score)" 
 TableName="tblStaffs" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" >
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470251%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you need to use [aggregate queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access the object properties. It also creates an object called `key` with the values used to group by.

```
Select="new (max(staffID) as staffID, key.Forename, key.Surname, max(City) as City, max(Country) as Country, max(LastUpdatedDate) as LastUpdatedDate, max(tblStaffStatus) as tblStaffStatus, max(Score) as Score)"
```

If you are grouping by a single value then use

```
GroupBy="Surname"
Select="new (key as Surname)"
```